# Making URL routes case-insensitive for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a rails route that goes to the

```
#works for "/profile/abc"
/profile/:id
```

However, it breaks when the url's id is capitalized

```
#breaks for "/profile/Abc"
/profile/:id
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Most likely it's the problem of the way you do find.

What's your database?
Could you post the code of your profile#show action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify constraints for `id` explicitly (if Rails says 'no such route'), like

```
map.connect '/profile/:id', ..., :constraints => { :id => /.+/ }
```

[On constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints)

Then, in your view, you can convert `params[:id]` to lower case. Also, if id has upper-case letters, you can redirect user to a proper (lower-case) url.

Although, reading the question again, I don't exactly understand what "breaks" means.